# What's the meaning of "**accept" in Proguard obfuscate source code?

Tags: proguard, obfuscation

When I read ProGuard's obfuscation source code.
There are many invocation of `**accept`,which are in `ClassPool`,such as `accept` `classesAccept` `classAccept`.
What's the meaning of these api?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ProGuard is implemented around the Visitor pattern idea. You will find this pattern almost anywhere in the codebase. The `accept` methods are used to apply the given visitor on the specific object.